# Linear regression model identifiable?

Tags: regression, definition, identifiability

I understand the concept of identifiability in the context of distributions. This is $f$ is identifiable if $f(x;\theta) = f(x;\theta')$ for all $x$, if and only if $\theta=\theta'$.

However, in the context of linear regression, I do not understand how to prove identifiability. In Wikipedia, it is stated that if the design matrix has rankk $p$, where $p$ is the number of covariates, then the model is identifiable:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identifiability#Example_3

**Question:** Can someone tell me the formal definition of identifiability in the context of regression models? Does the same definition applies to all regression models (e.g. non linear)?

Comment: It's exactly the same definition--there's no difference.  Bear in mind that the parameters in a regression model include the $p$ coefficients of the regressors.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "all values of the covariates."  The covariates already have their values.  Would you be able to specify your regression model explicitly?

Comment: "The same" is exactly as formal as the definition you gave in your first paragraph.  If you think it's not, that must be because you have some particular understanding of what "$f$" might mean for your regression model.  I'm just trying to get you to tell us what that model is so that we can all communicate better.

Comment: Please do not vandalyze your question. If you want to delete it, go ahead. Otherwise, leave it be.